# Optimizing Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on an app with six similar sections on the homepage. 
I have the app working but I had to repeat the block of code below:

The only thing different on each instance is id: `#grid` and id: `#close` as 
this ids vary on each of the six sections.

I try to clean this up by having line:

```
var $grid = $( '#grid4', '#grid2', '#grid3' ..... ),
```

and

```
$close = $( '#close', '#close2', '#close3', .....),
```

The previous prevents sections from loading on browser.

Here is the block of code that is being repeated:

```
$(function() {

    var $grid = $( '#grid' ),
      $name = $( '.name' ),
      $close = $( '#close' ),
      $loader = $( '<div class="loader"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><span>Loading...</span></div>' ).insertBefore( $grid ),
      stapel = $grid.stapel( {
        onLoad : function() {
          $loader.remove();
        },
        onBeforeOpen : function( pileName ) {
          $name.html( pileName );
        },
        onAfterOpen : function( pileName ) {
          $close.show();
        }
      } );

    $close.on( 'click', function() {
      $close.hide();
      $name.empty();
      stapel.closePile();
    } );

} );
```

How can I improve the code so I don't have to repeat the previous block? (keeping in mind that I do need to keep different ids as I need each section to behave independently)

Comment: @RobG Thought it was obvious given the tilte and explanation. I will edit and add question. Can you undo vote down?

Comment: —not my down vote, thanks for adding a question. The subject is usually just an attention grabber, you should try to be explicit with what you are trying to achieve (as you've done) in the actual post. "Optimising" means different things to different people (faster, less code, more maintainable, etc.). I'll give you +1 for your trouble. :-)

Comment: @RobG I see. I'll be more specific. Thank you (:

Comment: you should make a plugin based on an element then access each close/grid from that element within the plugin (& use class in html)would show you if you show your html structure

Answer (score 1):

You can use `class` instead of `id` to make `common` for all `elements` like

```
$grid = $( '.grid'),
```

And

```
$close = $( '.close')
```

Your **html** should be like,

```
<div class="grid">
    <!-- your html -->
    <div class="close">Close</div>
</div>
```

Now `close` is the child of `grid class` you can `extract` it by using [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find)

Comment: I need each section to behave independtly therfore I need different id

Comment: Using classes didn't do it and only first section loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multiple-selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
var $grid = $( '#grid4, #grid2, #grid3' ..... )
```

Comment: I just try. Sections still not loading on browser :/

Comment: Irm, note that there is only one argument in the function call. In your code there are several arguments separated by a comma, which is not correct I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables to make up selectors

```
 for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
     $('#grid' + i).....
     // will be #grid0, #grid1, #grid2, etc
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array and loop through it.

```
var grid= ["#grid4","#grid2","#grid3"];
for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    //The rest of your code goes here goes here
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make the code run for all id simultaneously? It should run independently for the specific section selected by the user.